# Can I stream a Binary from mongodb with spring?

Tags: spring-mongodb

I am searching for a way to improve my spring boot service, especially memory consumption. With binary data it is best to stream them from the source to the response, compared to load the whole `byte[]` into memory.
For files from the file system this is easy (just a silly example):

```
@GetMapping("/download/{fileName}")
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource > downloadFile(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) {
    FileSystemResource fileResource= new FileSystemResource(STORAGE_LOCATION + fileName);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.parse("attachment; filename=" + fileName));
    headers.setContentLength(fileResource.contentLength());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(fileResource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But I also store some binary data within a mongodb using th `org.bson.types.Binary` type. My question is, will this be loaded into memory anyway when I load the "Document" or is there a way to stream it from mongodb directly?

I only see that there is a `getData()` method on the `Binary` which already is the `byte[]`.